# get-wmiobject win32_physical memory count

Tags: powershell

I am using the following script:

```
get-wmiobject -class win32_physicalmemory | select Name, Model, Speed, Capacity, DeviceLocator
```

and the output lists the 4 piece of memory, but what I want to do is count number of physical memory and **then** list the model, speed, capacity and device locator.

I have tried using:

```
(get-wmiobject -class win32_physicalmemory | select Name, Model, Speed, Capacity, DeviceLocator).count
```

But this just returns 4, as opposed to 4 *and* the additional properties.

Answer (score 1):

You can always do this in two parts:

```
$mem = get-wmiobject -class win32_physicalmemory | select Name, Model, Speed, Capacity, DeviceLocator
"Count is $($mem.count)"
$mem
```